# Single-sex species that has specific culture roles for different body types?

Tags: xenobiology, aliens, culture, sex, gender

Basically what the title question says. I want there to at least be three socially constructed genders, each with their own expectations of how they should act and dress. I want the species to have a history of intense and harmful sexism -- genderism? -- that they've mostly gotten past by the time the story starts. But how do i make this unique instead of Male versus Female with Vague Extras?

Reproduction is like this: one sex, which is capable of mating with multiple individuals and producing a single child that shares DNA with three, or more, parents. I'm pretty sure they're born through live-birth, perhaps slightly akin to marsupials in that they are born extremely small and fragile (no pouches though). I say "single child" but they can have more than one at once. Please let me know if i need to explain more.

Comment: What you want is called castes. Those exist in some societies (even modern ones), and also in some social insect species. The difference is yours would have a sexual component added to them.

Comment: So like a more complicated version of queens soldiers and workers in ant societies? It's not exactly impossible to make them reproduce via a variation of parthenogenisis.

Comment: How does the reproduction system work (how babies are made and born)? Are there any noticeable physical differences between different members of society (can be literally anything if they exist at all)? I have some ideas, but I need additional information.

Comment: How does copulation work?

Comment: As it is now, the question is impossible to answer. Genders are based on biological sex and biological sex roles. You need to provide additional information about these.

Answer (score 7):

I already wrote this in another answer of mine, I think it applies also here:

several years ago I read about an anthropologist who wanted to study a tribe of hunter-gatherers and was admitted as a member of the tribe. Of course the first problem was what would have he been doing as a tribe member.

The tribe had 4 roles with 4 different tasks:

- man: hunting
- woman: harvesting fruits
- boy: harvesting water and supplies
- girl: make jewelry by working ostrich egg shells

He started off as a man, but failed because he was too smelly to be a good hunter. Then as a woman he wasn't able to harvest ripe fruits. Then as a boy he could not find water or enough wood/stones. Therefore he ended up as a girl, polishing ostrich egg shells all day long.

As you can see, the role was not based on physical features but on what the individual could provide for the group. And this can depend on the body type, since for example certain tasks are better accomplished with slender fingers rather than with sheer force.

Comment: These look more like social roles which depend on sex and age. Most aspects of gender roles are independent of age. I wonder if that anthropologist was treated like a girl in all regards? Or was he only assigned a girl's task?

Answer (score 0):

**"Gender" is actually ethnic differences.**

We base gender on biological sex.  Your people don't have that.  So cultural differences must be based on something else.  In human cultures we have used inherited phenotypic differences.

For example the "Untouchable" caste in India.

[ORIGIN OF THE UNTOUCHABLES OF SOUTH INDIA](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44139349?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

> To the question "who were the Untouchables of South India ?"  only
> three possible answers can be given, namely that they were  Aryan,
> Pre-Dravidian, or Dravidian (groups of people speaking  different
> languages and following different cultures). Scholars  disagree only
> with regard to the identification of the untouchables  with any of
> these three races (meaning three distinct cultural groups  rather than
> ethnic units); they are all agreed on one point namely  that they are
> the most ancient people of India...

The theory is that the original human groups in India persisted after subsequent groups came, and the caste system was a way to systematically disadvantage original peoples / advantage invaders.  Everyone can think of analogous situations in other cultures: persons from a specific background, possibly with a characteristc phenotype, who because of this assume prescribed cultural roles.

Your genders are descended from phenotypically different members of the same species.  If you call it "gender" because you want some of the caste roles to be sexual, that is fine.  Just as gender is a handy hook on which to hang cultural trappings, so is caste or as we would call it in the US, race.